# How do I remove old Ubuntu versions

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uninstall

I've installed 14.04 "alongside" my older versions of Ubuntu, and now I want to delete the older ones, which are taking up too much space.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Are the Operating Systems on the same disk or are they on multiple ones?

If there is more than one operating system on the disk, then you can use [Gparted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/) to reformat the partitions so you can use them as data partitions.

You can use

```
lsblk
```

to list all of the partitions so you know which one to blow away by looking at the mount point. e.g the line

```
└─sda5   8:5    0  80.7G  0 part /
```

would been that device is the root file system of the current os so you know not to reformat that partition.

It is possible to move different parts of your file system to different partitions, but some directories can't be in a partition of their own.

Visit [this website](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PartitioningSchemes#Basic_Partitioning_Scheme_for_a_2TB_Desktop_HDD) for more information on splitting up ubuntu into multiple partitions.

Also, consider reconfiguring grub so that you don't get the deleted operating systems listed in the menu.To do this try using either of these two commands but I haven't tried them myself so I don't know if they will work.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub
```

--or--

```
sudo update-grub
```

Please let me know if you have any more problems.

Comment: Thanks, @Spike347; I hadn't known about the lsblk command.  I'll look at what that gives me, as well as at the Partitioning website, and I'll probably have more questions tomorrow.